# Desserialize json with string,int array - .net core C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core

This is my first question on stackoverflow - so far I've always found a solution here :)

I am trying to deserialise JSON object. The problem is the 'count' list, because elements may change - name and value.
I think it's best to use the Dictionary for this - but the compiler throws errors.

```
{
  "count": [
    {"apple": 2},
    {"strawberry": 8},
    {"pear": 2}
  ],
  "on_plate": true,
  "owner": "Billy"
}
```

my c# class:

```
    public class FruitsDTO
    {
        public Dictionary<string, int> count { get; set; }
        public bool on_plate{ get; set; }
        public string owner{ get; set; }
    }
```

```
var respResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FruitsDTO>(jsonObject);
```

and result:
*Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.*

**EDITED**

Thanks @Phuzi and @Prasad Telkikar :)

I change class to:

```
    public class FruitsDTO
    {
        public Dictionary<string, int> count { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, int> Count2
            {
                get => Count.SelectMany(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
            }
        public bool on_plate{ get; set; }
        public string owner{ get; set; }
    }
```

Count2 - that's exactly what i need.

bool_plate - it's just a typo when renaming in the correct class for the sake of this example

Comment: Try `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` instead

Comment: `bool_plate` / `on_plate` should also have a type

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Updated my comment ;o)

Comment: Just want know why your updated class is different with the answer's class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Phuzi said, type of `count` variable should be `List<Dictionary<string, int>>>` not only `Dictionary<string, int>>`.

If you notice in json object count property consist of list of fruits, not a single fruit

Update your DTO as below,

```
public class FruitsDTO
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, int>> count { get; set; }  //Update type to list
    public bool on_plate { get; set; }   //update property name to on_plate
    public string owner { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize,

```
var respResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FruitsDTO>(jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 Options for this

Option 1, use a dictionary with a key value pair.

Option2 define a class for count.

Add another class:

```
public class FruitsDTO
{
    public List<FruitCounter> count { get; set; }
    public bool bool_plate{ get; set; }
    public string owner{ get; set; }
}

public class FruitCounter
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
}
```